# Normalisation and multi-valued fields

Tags: sql, ms-access, database-design

I'm having a problem with my students using multi-valued fields in access and getting confused about normalisation as a result.

Here is what I can make out. Given a 1-to-many relationship, e.g.

```
Articles    Comments
--------    --------
artID{PK}   commID{PK}
text        text
            artID{FK}
```

Access makes it possible to store this information into what appears to be one table, something like

```
Articles
--------
artID{PK}
text
comment
   + value
```

"value" referring to multiple comment values for the comment "column", which access actually stores as a separate table. The specifics of how the values are stored - table, its PK and FK - is completely hidden, but it is possible to query the multi-valued field, e.g. in the example above with the query

```
INSERT INTO article( [comment].Value )
VALUES ('thank you')
WHERE artID = 1;
```

But the query doesn't quite reveal the underlying structure of the hidden table implementing the multi-valued field.

Given this (disaster, in my view) - my problem is how to help newcomers to database design and normalisation understand what Access is offering them, why it may not be helpful, and that it is not a reason to ignore the basics of the relational model. More specifically:

- Are there better ways, besides queries as above, to reveal the structure behind multi-valued fields?
- Are there good examples of where the multi-valued field is not good enough, and shows the advantage of normalising explicitly?
- Are there straightforward ways to obtain the multi-select visual output of Access multi-values, but based on separate, explicit tables?

Thanks!

Comment: Multivalue fields are similar in many ways to look-ups, so http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm. They are mainly of value with Sharepoint and the advice is usually to not use them unless you are using Sharepoint. Copying tables with SQL (select into, insert into) also will not work. It may be a good time for your students to learn that applications sometimes have anti-features :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot give you advice in using this feature, because I never used it; however, I can give you reasons not to use it.

- I want to have full control on what I'm doing. This is not the case for multi-valued fields, therefore I don't use them.
- This feature is not expandable. What if you want to add a date field to your comments, for instance?
- It is sometimes necessary to upsize an Access (backend) database to a "big" database (SQL Server, Oracle). These Databases don't offer such a feature. It is often the customer who decides which database has to be used. Recently I had to migrate an Access application (frontend) using an Oracle backend to a SQL-Server backend because my client decided to drop his Oracle server. Therefore it is a good idea to restrict yourself to use only common features.
- For common tasks like editing lookup tables I created generic forms. My existing solutions will not work with multi-valued fields.
- I have a (self-made) tool that synchronizes changes in the structure of the database on my developer’s site with the database on the client’s site. This tool cannot deal with multi-valued fields.
- I have tools for the security management that can grant SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE rights on tables or revoke them. Again, the management tool does not work with multi-valued fields.
- Having a separate table for the comments allows you to quickly inspect all the comments (by opening the table). You cannot do this with multi-valued fields.
- You will not see the 1 to n relation between the articles and the comments in a database diagram.
- With a separate table you can choose whether you want to cascade deletes to the details table or not. If you don't, you will not be able to delete an article as long as there are comments attached to it. This can be desirable, if you want to protect the comments from being deleted inadvertently.

Comment: Thanks @Olivier - I had the 1-to-n and lack of control problems in mind, but your compatibility examples are very useful. Also simply the views  of somebody with experience - believe it or not, students like the voice of authority when they hear it.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to realize the difference between physical and logical relationships. Today the whole internet and web services (SOAP) quite much realizes on a data format that is multi-value in nature.

When you represent multi-value data with a relational database (such as Access), then behind the scenes you are using a traditional (and legitimate) relation.  I cannot stress that as such, then the use of multi-value columns in Access is in fact a LEGITIMATE relational model.

The fact that table is not exposed does not negate this issue. In fact, if you represent an invoice (master record, and repeating details) as a XML data cube, then we see two things:

1) you can build and represent that invoice with a relational database like Access
2) such a relational data model that is normalized can ALSO be represented as a SINGLE xml string.
3) deleting the XML record (or string) means that cascade delete of the child rows (invoice details) MUST occur.

So while it is true that Multi-Value fields been added to Access to deal with SharePoint, it is MOST important to realize that such data can be mapped to a relational database (if you could not do this, then Access could not consume that XML data using relational database tables as ACCESS CURRENTLY DOES RIGHT NOW).

And with the web such as XML, and SharePoint then the need to consume and manage and utilize such data is not only widespread, but is in fact a basic staple of the internet.

As more and more data becomes of a complex nature, we find the requirement for multi-value data exploding in use. Anyone who used that so called "fad" the internet is thus relying and using data that is in fact VERY OFTEN XML and is multi-value (complex) in nature.

As long as the logical (not physical) relational data model is kept, then use of multi-value columns to represent such data is possible and this is exactly what Access is doing (it is mapping the relational data model to a complex model).  Note that the complex (xml) data model does NOT necessary have to be relational in nature. However, if you ARE going to map such data to Access then the complex multi-value model MUST CONFORM TO A RELATIONAL data model.

This is EXACTLY what is occurring in Access.

The fact that such a correct and legitimate math relational model is not exposed is of little issue here. Are we to suggest that because Excel does not expose the binary codes used then users will never learn about computers? Or perhaps we all must program in assembler so we all correctly learn how computers works.

At the end of the day, who cares and why does this matter? The fact that people drive automatic cars today does not toss out the concept that they are using different gears to operate that car.  The idea that we shut down all of society because someone is going to drive an automatic car or in this case use complex data would be galactic stupid on our part.

So keep in mind that extensions to SQL do exist in Access to query the multi-value data, but as well pointed out here those underlying tables are not exposed. However, as noted, exposing such tables would STILL REQUIRE one to not change or mess with cascade delete since that feature is required TO MAINTAIN A INTERSECTION OF FEATURES and a CORRECT MATH relational model between the complex data model (xml) and that of using two related tables to represent such data.

In other words, you can use related tables to represent the complex data model IF YOU REMOVE the ability of users to play with the referential integrity options. The RI options MUST remain as set in those hidden tables else such data will not be able to make the trip BACK to the XML or complex data model of which it was consumed from.

As noted, in regards to users being taught how gasoline reacts with oxygen for that of learning to drive a car, or using a word processor and being forced to learn a relational model and expose the underlying  tables makes little sense here.

However, the points made here in regards to such tables being exposed are legitimate concerns.

The REAL problem is SQL server and Oracle etc. cannot consume or represent that complex data WHILE ACCESS CAN CONSUME such data.

As noted, the complex data ship has LONG ago sailed! XML, soap, and the basic technologies of the internet are based on this complex data model.

In effect, SQL server, Oracle and most databases cannot that consume this multi-value data represent it without users having to create and model such data in a relational fashion is a BIG shortcoming of SQL server etc.

Access stands alone in this ability to consume this data.

So, for anyone who used a smartphone, iPad or the web, you are using basic technologies that are built around using complex data, something that Access now allows.

It is likely that the rest of the industry will have to follow suit given that more and more data is complex in nature. If the database industry does not change, then the mainstream traditional relational database system will NOT be the resting place of such data.

A trend away from storing data in related tables is occurring at a rapid pace right now and products like SharePoint, or even Google docs is proof of this concept. So Access is only reacting to market pressures and it is likely that other database vendors will have to follow suit or simply give up on being part of the "fad" called the internet.

XML and complex data structures are STAPLE and fact of our industry right now – this is not an issue we all should run away from, but in fact embrace.

```
Albert D. Kallal (Access MVP)
Edmonton, Alberta Canada
kallal@msn.com
```

Comment: XML and complex data structures are staple, and our data needs are evolving to requiring such systems, yet that doesn't mean multi-valued fields are among the best responses. But I like the XML example - it's a good example of a different mapping between physical and logical, and it is transparent.

Comment: Access mv columns are missing several features that other MV systems (pick for example) had for dealing with xml data. MAJOR feature missing is ability to assign controlling and dependent columns in such xml data (this setting is required to maintain the relational model with xml data). So the idea of using a correct relational data model to hold XML data (as access does) is not only a great solution, but one that should be MORE often used in our industry. This means you can use SQL and a LOGICAL relational view of such data as opposed to using DOM and xml library to manipulate such data.

Answer (score 2):

The technical discussion is interesting.  I think the real problem lies in student understanding.  Because it is available in Access students will use it, and initially it will probably provide a simple solution to some design problems.  The negatives will occur later when they try and use the data.  Maybe a simple example demonstrating the problems would persuade some students to avoid using multi-valued fields ?  Maybe an example of storing the data in another, more usable format would help ?

Good luck !

Peter Bullard

Comment: Nice to hear from you Peter :) I will probably work to prepare such an example, probably something that involves multiple fields in the "sub" table. I just can't believe we're having to battle with software that doesn't implement the relational model... Again... When actually, making the separate table for multi-value fields explicitly visible would have been so simple, and lead to an equally good front end. Shame.

Answer (score 1):

MS Access does a great job of simplifying database management and abstracting out a lot of complexity. This however makes the learning of dbms concepts a bit difficult. Have you tried using other 'standard' dbms tools like MySQL (or even sqlite). From a learning perspective they may be better.

Comment: I agree, and for visual front-ends I'm considering Libre Office as well. But I don't think I can ignore access completely - too well-known to avoid. And some students would end up using it at home and remain confused.

Comment: Access is a **lot** more than a database, it is a RAD tool, a reporting tool etc, etc and cannot easily be replaced, especially for the small user, with other single application on the market.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old.  But, it's not quite the same as every other post I've seen on this topic.  This one has someone making a good case for using Multi Valued Fields...

As someone who is trying who is still trying very hard to get their head around Access, I find the discussion for and against using the Multi Valued Fields incredibly frustrating.

I'm trying to sort through it all, but if everyone is so against them, what is an alternative method?  It seems that in every search result I find everyone is either telling you how to use Multi Valued Fields and Controls or telling you how horrible and what a mistake they are.  Many people refer to an alternative to them, but nobody says "Here's an example".  I'm here to learn about these things.  And while I know that this is a simpler concept for a lot of people in these forums, I could really use some examples to take a look at.

I'm at a point where I have to decide which way to go.  It would be wonderful to compare examples of using Multi Valued Fields and alternatives and using a control to select multiple values.

Or am I wrong and the functionality of a combobox where you can select multiple items is only available through Access?

Comment: The alternative method to multi-value fields is what everyone else does, and the reason why no-one else develops software with multi-valued fields: they use link tables. If a table needs a multi-valued field, it needs another table even more. Do yourself a favour and don't use multi-valued fields when you can do the same of better with separate tables and foreign keys.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Boisvert.  I don't want to limit myself to shortcuts that won't apply anywhere else or make things more difficult in the long run.  Would I use a combobox or listbox with the linked table? And would it be apparent to the User that they can select multiple items?

Comment: I'd say that's the sort of thing to make a separate question about. Find an example of the problem, and if your development skills are more visual, use a screenshot or two.

Answer (score 0):

I want to address the last of your questions first.  There is a way of providing a visual presentation of a parent child relationship.  It's called subforms.  If you get help about subforms in Access, it will explain the concept.
I have used subforms in a project where I wanted to display the transaction header in a form and the transaction details in a subform.  There is nothing to hinder this construct even when the data is stored in two normalized tables.

Of course, this affects the screen, not the database.  That's the whole point.  Normalization is relevant to storage and retrieval, not to other uses of data.